# Custom Scrolling for DIV / Section

Tags: css, html, scroll

This is the antiscroll which I use 
https://github.com/LearnBoost/antiscroll

on my website I have  middle section with code:

```
<section id="middleSection">  </section>
```

And with CSS:

```
#middleSection{

    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 68px;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 150px;
    right: 200px;

}
```

If I use antiscroll code it was fine to insert a separate box inside  my middleSection, but I can't adapt this code to make the actual middleSection with this acntiscrollbar.

Basically I need to make this middle section with antiscroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, if you know and understand jQuery library, I recommend on this plugin:

[LINK](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

It's an awesome plugin, which is very simple.